# how create "char**" variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dll, ffi, ref

I use dll file which include this function:

```
unsigned long PPRRN(CAxECRClass98* obj, char**RRN, double total_amount, double add_amount );
```

```
var ref = require("ref-napi");
var ffi = require("ffi-napi");
var MyLibrary = ffi.Library('./AxECR98.so', 

{
"PosPurchaseRRN":["ulong", [myobjPtr,"char**", "double", "double",]],
});
```

how i can to create variable for second argument?

Comment: char** is basically only array/list of strings in context of Javascript, so to answer your question the parameter should be something like this ['blah','foo'].

Answer (score 0):

```
var testp = ref.alloc('char **');
var someBuffer = new Buffer("yout_text");

ref.writePointer(testp,0,someBuffer);
```

testp is your variable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).